# Removing .aspx from pages using rewriteModule?

Tags: .net, web-config, url-rewriting

I'm using ASP .NET rewriteModule to rewrite http://example.com to http://www.example.com.

```
<section name="rewriteModule" type="RewriteModule.RewriteModuleSectionHandler, RewriteModule"/>
```

Then i have this inside `<system.webServer>`.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+[.]com)$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Now i want to remove all the .aspx in the end of my pages. Example:

http://www.example.com/Register.aspx

Will turn into:

http://www.example.com/Register/

How can i do that?

**I'm on Shared Web Hosting on GoDaddy using IIS7.**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are the standard rewrite rules I start every project with. I use only clean URLs for all the pages (example first rule works for www.example.com/about and second rule www.example.com/product/123)

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
  <rule name="Rewrite default to aspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Rewrite page to aspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
  </rule> 
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Pages where I need to parse out the ID (this case number only) and add it to the query string I add a similar rule to the front:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Product ID" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^product/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="product.aspx?id={R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

If you want to use lower and upper case letters in the URL, set ignoreCase="true"

**Edit to answer your second question plus a bonus**

This rule will redirect aspx page to the clean URL:

```
<rule name="Redirect to clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

Replace url="{R:1}" with url="{ToLower:{R:1}}" to change URL to lowercase. See below why you would want to do this.

Also a good idea to update the Form action so that post backs don't return back to the ugly URL. Using IIS 7.5 or newer this should work:

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.RawUrl))
        form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```

or for IIS 7:

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"]))
        form1.Action = Context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"];
```

One more thing to keep in mind... it's a good idea to keep all URLs lower case. Mixing lower/upper case characters in the URL creates duplicate content issues for SEO/Google. For example website.com/About and website.com/about will load the same page, but Google will index them as two separate pages.

Comment: You are the man !
Just one thing if you know how to do, now i need to send them toe the URL and it adds the aspx without them seeing, but is it possible that if they go to the .aspx it will remove the .aspx ?

Comment: Updated the answer to include your second question.

Comment: I tried using this for my URL rewirte in one of my projects. the removing extension worsk perfectly. however, i seem to be getting issues with the pop ups of Ajax. in my Modal Popup extender and calender pop up extenders.i did raise a ticket on this. but no response so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243017/url-rewrite-create-compactible-issues-with-ajaxtoolkit

Answer (score 5):

First you need to remove the .aspx (**default.aspx**) and redirect to **default** to change the browser address then add the .aspx and rewire to page using IIS

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to clean URL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RewriteASPX" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Serge's answer was informative, but your was working. Thanks dude. :)

Comment: its give me the follwing error 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /collections/.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
            <remove name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" />
            <remove name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" />
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^www\.myserver\.com/(.*)\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="www.myserver.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^www\.myserver\.com/(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="www.myserver.com/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <remove name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" />
            <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL2" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*)www\.myserver\.com/(.*)\.aspx$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="www.myserver.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

this will do it - I have generated this vis IIS on my local machine - change myserver.com to your own URL. you can change the regex to actually take care of the x.aspx part of the url then it should work across all pages

Comment: @stack Nice thx, but i want all pages to look friendly not just the Register.aspx, for example i also has Login.aspx and Products.aspx and alot more.

Comment: @stack Me and RegEx doesn't go well together xD
So if you can show me an example i will be happy :)

Comment: try the updated rule - this has a catch all instead of hardcoded register - this will need tested across pages for exclusions

Comment: @stack i get "500 (Internal Server) Error".

Comment: have you changed the myserver.com to be your own url?

Comment: @stack Yes, changed. still 500

Comment: can you take your rule and create a pastebin.org snippet and post the link here - make sure and take out your site url and replace with a www.test.com or whatever

Comment: I have updated the rule to take into account the 'www.' infront of the server url - can you try that - this works for me on test rules