# remove .aspx extention using IIS7 & URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing .aspx from pages using rewriteModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097592/removing-aspx-from-pages-using-rewritemodule)

I want to remove .aspx extension from the url. Using IIS7 & URL Rewrite.
In my web.config file I have the below code, When I browse a aspx file (e.g. test.aspx) it still shows .aspx in the browser. Am I missing anything? Thanks

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="Remove .aspx from URL" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)\.aspx$" />
       <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
     </rule>       
   </rules>      
 </rewrite>  
 </system.webServer>
```