# Removing .aspx from pages using URL Rewrite in iis in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I want to remove .aspx from my webpage in ASP.Net. I download URL Rewrite Module and installed to winserver 2008 and this:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite [^]

I'm a beginner and I tried

I also tried [remove .aspx extention using IIS7 & URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216673/remove-aspx-extention-using-iis7-url-rewrite)

but it dosen't work.

for example change default.aspx ---> default
How do I do this?

---

i get error 404 - File or directory not found.
when i use this code:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite aspx" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

please F1F1F1F1F1

Comment: Consider using MVC instead of WebForms...

Comment: Look into this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx maybe it helps

Comment: I just needed to change ([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$ to ([a-z0-9/-]+).aspx$ so the redirect would work with hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
U can do this in your web.config file itself

 <system.web>

    <urlMappings enabled="true">

        <add url="~/marutisuzuki-Alto" mappedUrl="~/Carmodel.aspx?carname=Alto&amp;carid=6"/>
</urlMappings>
</system.web>

If you add this if any page with this "~/Carmodel.aspx?carname=Alto&amp;carid=6" is replaced by "~/marutisuzuki-Alto".
```

Comment: tnx subinpanicker,but users can type default.aspx,and it's not friendly for search engineers-the search engine can see both default.aspx and default

Comment: i try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097592/removing-aspx-from-pages-using-rewritemodule but get error

Answer (score 0):

With URL Rewrite Module try this in your web.config (inside system.webServer element):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite aspx" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: where have you put the rule? and what error says when browsing on server from IIS? I guess you have now wrong format of web.config. Try also to open URL Rewrite from IIS to see what it says about error

Comment: I just needed to change ([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$ to ([a-z0-9/-]+).aspx$ so the redirect would work with hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

my web config :

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
        <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
    <rewrite>
        <rule name="Rewrite aspx" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>



    </rewrite>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
        </system.webServer>
<appSettings>

    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>


    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage" />
    <!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10480" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />

</system.web>

<!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
```

Comment: You are missing <rules> parent element for <rule>. It should be structured like rewrite -> rules -> rule
(It was already in my answer)