# Asp.net url rewriting altindovizfiyatlari.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

i wanna ask you something

I have a website

http://altindovizfiyatlari.net i coded this site Asp.net(C#)

i want to make UrlReWrite for remove .aspx extension I researched this problem but i didn't solve it.

My site has no QueryString so onyl got simple web pages

for example

http://altindovizfiyatlari.net/usd-kur.aspx

I want to change it www.altindovizfiyatlari.net/usd-kur/ 
is this possible and how ?

please help

very thanks.

Comment: Yes this is possible, however you wouldn't have a slash on the end.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097592/removing-aspx-from-pages-using-rewritemodule

Comment: Matthew thank you very much i added web.config but this time  give "Unrecognized configuration section rewrite." message. How am i add to configuration section to web.config file ? Do you know ? by the way thank you.