# Ajax call not working when keeping a webpage in folder in url rewriting

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**My ajax call**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",           
            url: '../User/UserRegister.aspx/InsertMethod',
            data: "{'FirstName':'" + "Test" + "'}", 
            async: false,
            success: function (obj) {
                if (obj.d == 'abc') {                  
                }
                else {                  
                }

        }
    });
```

**My Method in UserRegister.aspx.cs:-****

```
[WebMethod]
public static string InsertMethod(string FirstName)
{
    return FirstName;
}
```

**In my Webconfig:-**

```
<rewrite url="~/User/UserRegister" to="~/User/UserRegister.aspx"/>
```

**My href from where i call my page:-**

```
sbMenu.Append("<li><a href=" + "http://localhost:1234/User/UserRegister" + ">" + "User" + "</a></li>");
```

***Note***:-When I use the page outside the folder this works perfectly
Project-->UserRegister.aspx but not working when using project-->User(Folder)-->Userregister.aspx(Page).My Project is in Vs2012.I have used intelligencia.Urlrewrite dll.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use ResolveUrl.

Comment: @gmd : i have used ResolvedUrl in ajax call as well as in my <a href>. but its not working..

Comment: What you put in Resolve url?

Comment: I have used below code in href :

sbMenu.Append("<li><a href='" + ResolveUrl("http://localhost:33917/User/UserRegister") + "'>User</a></li>");

And I have used below code as a Ajax call.

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("UserRegister.aspx/InsertMethod") %>',     
        data: "{'FirstName':'" + "Test" + "'}",
        async: false,
        success: function (obj) {          
            if (obj.d == 'abc') {}
            else {} }
    });
 
should i use ResolveUrl in both Ajax and href?

Comment: Use resolve url in ajax only, something like
url: '<%=ResolveUrl("User/UserRegister.aspx/InsertMethod") %>' or
url: '<%=ResolveUrl("/User/UserRegister.aspx/InsertMethod") %>'

Comment: I have tried both but it is not working...any other suggestions??

Comment: I did test with '../User/UserRegister.aspx/InsertMethod' and          'UserRegister.aspx/InsertMethod' without using resolve url & with rewrite it is working, please check console error log.

Comment: @gmd : i have tried this also. but not getting actual output. can you please post your code here or send me as a compressed file. i will compare with my code and will change.

Comment: I have used your code, with new demo project, in that i kept UserRegister page within User folder. I used this answer for rewriting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097592/removing-aspx-from-pages-using-rewritemodule/15240694#15240694.