# How can I pass a query string in a route in a web forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database that returns data based on the query string. My url is formatted like this

```
www.example.com/CompanyPage.aspx?id=(some number)
```

I want to set up routing so that I can pass a human friendly url instead

```
www.example.com/CompanyPage.aspx/(company name)
```

I inserted a Global.asax file into my web forms project, and set up routing like this.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Burger_Hut", "CompanyPage.aspx?id=32", "~/CompanyPage.aspx");
}
```

The problem is that I get an error stating that

```
The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUrl
```

All my googling takes me to how to fix this via MVC. But this is not an MVC project. It's a webforms project. Can someone point my in the right direction on this? Is routing the proper way to go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try  `routes.MapPageRoute("Burger_Hut", "CompanyPage/{id}", "~/CompanyPage.aspx");`

Comment: @Developer How would this work though? Don't I have to specificy which ID goes with what company name?

Comment: "Id" should be dynamic, there is no point in hardcoding it in your route. That placeholder {id} could take any value you put in the route. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: But I make sql calls with a where clause that contains the page ID. So how do I get 

www.example.com/CompanyPage.aspx/Burger_Hut 
to turn into 
www.example.com/CompanyPage.aspx?id=32

Or turn 'Burger_Hut' into '32'

Comment: I've used IIS Redirect (need plugin if not already installed) extensively for this stuff. It's dead simple and works well, especially for Web Forms projects, though it's great for MVC too. Redirects are set up via rules in your Web.config file.

Comment: Ooh gotcha, I think I read your question wrong or got misdirected when I saw routing configuration. In this case, Im not sure whether routing is gonna help unless you could identify the record in database from the company name you are passing in the route, i.e. "Burger_Hut" in above example. If you can uniquely identify the record using "Burger_Hut" instead of id (32), then have the route as ....\{name} instead of {id} and query the database accordingly

Comment: Visit this link i think it'll help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097592/removing-aspx-from-pages-using-rewritemodule