# Web config redirects going to .aspx version instead of clean version

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My code to redirect `www` and `http` to `https://example.com/*`

```
    <rule name="NonWwwRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Which works, kinda. Problem is, as an example, the redirect always goes to `https://example.com/hello.aspx` instead of `https://example.com/hello`

I'm using this to make non-aspx URLs work, which they do, just the redirect chooses to go to the .aspx version.

```
    <rule name="RewriteASPX">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

Has anybody got any idea what the issue is?

> EDIT: Any non-aspx URL redirects to the .aspx version.

Answer (score -1):

For details on how to remove the `.aspx` extension take a look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097592/removing-aspx-from-pages-using-rewritemodule)

For information on https and www rewrites take a look at [this elmah blog post](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/)