# Remove file extensions in URL asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, seo

I'm currently using URL Rewriting in my website.

If the URL is `www.mywebsite.com/orders/Default.aspx?id=100`

It makes the Url as `www.mywebsite.com/orders/100`

If some one tries to hack the URL and enter unknown values I redirect to Home page

Now what I need is, If some one try to hack the URL and add extensions like `.aspx`,`.jsp`,`.html`,`.html`, ....

for ex: `www.mywebsite.com/orders/100.aspx` (After Hack).

I want to remove those extensions and take the query string as `www.mywebsite.com/orders/100` only and process it.

I saw this type of behavior in StackOverflow.

Can I achieve this? If YES How ???

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @m4ngl3r This link does not contain answers for my question. It just says methods of URL Rewriting.

Comment: You may have to install a rewrite module in IIS and then set it in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Something like you have to configure in the web config file

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteASPX">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This was taken from following links

[Remove HTML or ASPX Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481632/remove-html-or-aspx-extension)