# how to disable url masking in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have an application which points to a URL http://localhost:64162/webform1.aspx

But when run the application, it shows the URLwithout extension, http://localhost:64162/webform1 this repeats in the subsequent pages also.

I dont want the extension to be hide from the URL. I analyzed the global.aspx and web.config files for URLrewrite rules but couldn't find any.

Im using visual studio 2013 and IIS7.

How can I show the extension in my URL?

Comment: Recheck once more all the possible places - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481632/remove-html-or-aspx-extension. If that doesn't help, then try to create a new empty application to see whether it has the same issues, if not, then incrementally add parts from your current application - you will either find the culprit, or at the worst case end with exactly the same application, but without any url masking issues.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I tried it by creating a new empty application with IISexpress but got the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution in the [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/jkrebsbach/archive/2014/01/23/friendly-urls-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

I remove the friendlyURL from the installed nudgets and changed the below code in routeconfig.cs

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

by default it was    `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;`  .

also cleared the cache.

It works.