# ASP Url rewriting rule to get rid of extensions

Tags: asp.net, iis

Why is the following URL rewrite rule not working?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please copy the image to SO, because if the link goes dead then your question won't mean anything. Also, moving some of the text from the image into the question would make it easier to answer (because opening the image would be less important to understanding the question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML or ASPX Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481632/remove-html-or-aspx-extension)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern should be

```
^([a-z0-9/]+)$
```

And the action url

```
{R:1}.aspx
```