# .aspx at the end of a URL

Tags: asp.net

we access a customers website and at the end of the link we add the .aspx part. if we do not we get a 404 error.

The customer does not add the .aspx part when they access their own website and it works for them

Why would this be?

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: Sounds like their rewrite rules for stripping the ASPX in the URL for the site are not set up correctly on their end.  Are you adding "www" and they are not (or vice versa) for the domain, per chance? Have them send you the EXACT url which they are claiming you should be able to use.

It's their issue, they should troubleshoot this, not you.

Comment: no we are not adding www and nether are they

Answer (score 0):

This requires a URL rewrite. This might help you. They have solved their issue by removing the .aspx extension from their URL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4552992/3946804

Comment: the two parties are accessing the same URL.